# Validate Start Time With Current Date In Sharepoint?

Tags: validation, sharepoint, datetime, sharepoint-2010, calendar

I have a column called *Start Time* (it's a SharePoint Default Calendar Column). I need to validate if the *Start Time* is less than today or not? Without using javascript? Is this possible?

I have tried this:

1. Created a column called *Today* type as Date and Time.
2. Default value is current date.
3. Then compared the *Start Time* and *Today* in validation settings like the following:

   ```
   =[Start Time] < [Today]
   ```

it seems not working. help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code instead of yours

```
=[Start Time]<NOW()
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this to validate that Start Date must be less than or equal to Today:

```
=[Start Date]<=Today()
```

...and it works for me.